# Determine all three-digit positive integers *abc*

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Determine all three-digit positive integers *abc* (***a*** is hundreds ***b*** tens and ***c*** ones) such that 8*abc = 3*cba.

---

Here is my how I have started:

8 *(100a + 10b + c) = 3*(100c + 10b + a)

800a + 80b + 8c = 300c + 30b + 2a

797a + 50b - 292c = 0

50b = 292c - 797a

b = (292c - 797a)/50

Since abc and cba both need to be even we know that a must be even but not c because factor 292 makes the product even.

Then I started to test different values for ***a*** and ***c***, it didn't take so long because ***a*** can be larger than 2, so the only values I tested were 1 and 2 for ***a***. For c I tested all values up to 7 (then I found the answer) and it was kind of easy because you don't need to do the whole calculation since if the unit digit of the product of 292 multiplied by ***c*** minus 4 and 7 is not 0 we know that the difference is not divisible with 50.

So the only answer I found is ***c = 7***  and ***a = 2*** so ***b = 9***

But I can't prove it algebraically or write a better solution for this problem, I don't think testing is the best method for solving it...

Comment: Well... if all you are interested in is a proof it is correct writing a quick computer program will very quickly verify it.  `for(a=0;a<10;a++){for(b=0;b<10;b++){for(c=0;c<10;c++){if(8*(100*a+10*b+c)==3*(100*c+10*b+a)){console.log(a+' '+b+' '+c)}}}}` does indeed output only the two results: `0 0 0` and `2 9 7`.

Comment: And confirmed in *Mathematica*.  By the way, you can speed the above code by imposing the non-negativity constraint (e.g., $a \neq 0$), and the fact that $a$ is even.  This eliminates the improper "answer" (0,0,0).

Comment: "*speed up the code*"  It took less than a millisecond to run anyways, I didn't see it important to optimize it any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$797a+50b=292c$$
Here we see that $a$ must be even, and if $a\ge4$ then the LHS is too big for the RHS to match in magnitude (remember that $0\le c\le 9$). Hence $a=2$:
$$1594+50b=292c$$
Now we see that $c$ must be at least $6$ so that the RHS can match the LHS in magnitude, and must be $2$ or $7$ to match in the last digit (the LHS's last digit must be $4$). Hence $c=7$, from which we get $b=9$ and the unique solution as $\overline{abc}=297$.

Comment: How do we know that LHS's last digit must be 4?

Comment: @NegativeCreep $50b$ always ends in a zero, and $0+4=4$.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, is there an argument for why a cant be 1?

Comment: and you said that c must be at least 6, then how does it have to be 2 or 7. It can only be 7? Because 2<6.

Comment: if a >= 4 then it can be 1,2,3 and 4?  How can you say that it's 2 then?

Comment: @NegativeCreep In the first equation, $a$ cannot be odd since that would make the LHS odd, while the RHS must be even. The other constraints stem from $a,b,c$ being _digits_, which restricts the range of the RHS and thus the LHS. In the second equation, $50b$ can only end in a zero, so adding $1594$ means that the LHS must end in $4$, whereupon (as can be confirmed by just trying different digits $c$) $c$ must be $2$ or $7$.

Answer (score 1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[8*(a*100 + b*10 + c*1) == 3*(100*c + 10*b + 1*a)], {a, b, 
    c}, Nothing], {a, 1, 9}, {b, 1, 9}, {c, 1, 9}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={{{{2, 9, 7}}}}
```

So, we can see that you're right!

---

When we expand this, with different values of the constants before the numbers we get:

```
In[2]:=ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[4*(a*100 + b*10 + c*1) == 7*(100*c + 10*b + 1*a)], {a, b, 
    c}, Nothing], {a, 1, 9}, {b, 1, 9}, {c, 1, 9}] //. {} -> Nothing

Out[2]={{{{2, 3, 1}}}, {{{4, 6, 2}}}, {{{6, 9, 3}}}}
```